# How to set the background image only for a particular component in angular 6

Tags: css, angular, angular6

I have created new component called login,I have to set background image for the component(login.component.html),only for that component.I have tried many solutions provided in stack overflow.But the image is not setting to full height of the body.
Below are my project files.

index.html

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
     </head>
     <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
     </body>
   </html>
```

app.component.html

```
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module.ts

```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
   import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

   @Component({
     AppComponent,
     LoginComponent
   })
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     RouterModule.forRoot([
       { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },
       { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

           ])

          ],
        providers: [],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
             })

       export class AppModule { }
```

login.component.html

```
    <div class="inventory-body">
        <!--content goes here-->
    </div>
```

login.component.css

```
    .inventory-body {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    height:auto;
    background-image: url('/assets/img/1.jpg');
     }
```

Here is the login.component.ts file

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
     })
   export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

      }

     }
```

Comment: can you post login.component.ts file also

Comment: I have posted login.component.ts file

Comment: Is because you are setting height as auto. Try giving a fixed value for the height.

Comment: to test try using the selector inside the app.component.html and give the height and width as 100% in the login.component.css

Comment: I have tried giving fixed height value but it's repeating,that i have stopped by css background-repeat:no-repeat;  but it's not fitting same height for all devices.

Comment: I tried giving selector inside app.component.html still no result.@VaibhavKumarGoyal

Comment: To solve your multi device problem you can use media queries 
`@media (min-width: 601px) {
  #page {
    background: url('images/white-zigzag.png') repeat-x;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #page {      
     background: url('images/white-zigzag-mobile.png') repeat-x;
  }
}`

Comment: That i can try,but the default height of the image is 522px.Its not at all displaying up to that height in normal laptop size.

Comment: ok can you use the property background-size:100% and post the print screen?@Shankarguru

Comment: After giving background-size:100%; for the laptop its working fine,but not for tablets and mobiles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in global style(style.css)

```
    html, body, app-root {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     }
```

In (login.component.html)

```
    <body  class="inventory-body">

    </body>
```

Next write css(login.component.css) to the selector present in (login.component.html)

```
    .inventory-body {
     position: fixed;
     min-width: 100%;
     background-image: url("/assets/img/img-1.jpg");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100%;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: cover;
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.inventory-body {
 position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url('')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set height: auto, you must set html, body, and app-root height to 100% in styles.css (global css file). Do the same for the app.component in the app.component.css, and login.component in login.component.css.

[Live demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rquor)

Comment: I have tried the live demo code in my project,Still the image is repeating horizontally,That i stopped using background-repeat:no-repeat;  Then that part will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background-image', 'url(/assets/img/mybackgroundimage.png)');
  }
```